# Energized for vs. energized about

Tags: prepositions, expressions

"I’m extremely energized **for** what lies ahead of us" vs. "I’m extremely energized **about** what lies ahead of us". Which one sounds more natural to English speakers to describe excitement about future events in a team?

Comment: Do you want 'energised' to mean 'full of energy and stamina **for** the task that lies ahead' (e.g. you took vitamins, drank energy drinks, got a lot of sleep, etc before the task) or 'feeling excited and enthusiastic mentally **about** the task that lies ahead'?

Comment: The latter. Thanks. If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean 'energised' to mean that it has given you energy, then the correct preposition would be '**by**'.

Just look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=energised%20by%2C%20energised%20for%2C%20energised%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing the use of 'energised' with *by, for* & *about* and you'll see that is the usual preposition used with this word. It would be unusual to say you were energised "about" or "for" something.

On the other hand, if you're trying to use 'energised' to mean something else - perhaps excited - then I can see why you might have thought about using 'by' or 'about'. Most people would say they were excited *about* something, although we may say we are excited *for* something if it is more speculative.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "energized for" if it is about anticipating something that will happen. Similar to "excited for", "prepared for". But "about" is not necessarily wrong.